# Custom Canonical URLs

Tags: seo

I am moving my site from olddomain.com to newdomain.com. I want to keep all of the content at olddomain.com but I want the canonical version in google to be recognized as newdomain.com/whatever-post/ instead of the same thing at olddomain.com.

How can I modify the rel=canonical in the  section of olddomain.com to make this change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no filter in the `rel_canonical()` function. But you can remove that function from wp_head altogether and write your own. Try adding this to the functions.php at your old domain:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_canonical' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'new_rel_canonical' );

function new_rel_canonical() {
     if ( !is_singular() )
          return;

      global $wp_the_query;
      if ( !$id = $wp_the_query->get_queried_object_id() )
          return;

      $link = get_permalink( $id );
      $link = str_replace( 'olddomain.com', 'newdomain.com', $link );
      echo "<link rel='canonical' href='$link' />\n";
  }
```

Obviously, just replace olddomain.com and newdomain.com in the second to last line with your actual domain names!

Comment: Something relevant: https://gist.github.com/1217431

Answer (score 1):

There is a filter !

```
add_filter( 'get_canonical_url', 'myfunc', 10, 2);
function myfunc( $canonical_url, $post )
{
    ...
    ...
    return $canonical_url;
}
```